# Robot following another robot in navigation

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to make a robot follow another robot which would be controlled by keyboard. Simulation is in Gazebo How can I do that using ROS navigation? Is it possible?
I already managed to make that happen by making two topics. First robot is subscribing to the odometry of second robot and moving to it, but I would like to try that using navigation but don't have any ideas.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290724/robot-following-another-robot-in-navigation/) by [topkek](https://answers.ros.org/users/34642/topkek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2018-05-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you seen [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Introduction%20to%20tf)?

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2018-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [topkek](https://answers.ros.org/users/34642/topkek/) on 2018-05-09**:
Thx, i'll check it out